# Create ACL With Regex in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, regex

I want to conditionally add a header to requests that match a domain and its subdomains. So, I want to match a requests from:

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
http://foo.example.com
https://foo.example.com
```

But not:

```
http://example.com.otherdomain.com
```

I have these lines in my haproxy config.

```
frontend http
  capture request header origin len 128
  acl is_my_domain capture.req.hdr(0) /https?:\/\/(.*\.)?example.com/
  http-response add-header X-Your-Domain-IS %[capture.req.hdr(0)] if is_my_domain
```

I can get the captured data to echo out in a header,but the conditional doesn't work. How can I test the origin header like that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you would rather like to be using the following acl, it looks much more readable:

```
acl is_my_domain hdr_end(host) -i example.com
http-response add-header X-Your-Domain-IS %[host] if is_my_domain
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I receive the following error: `acl 'is_my_domain' will never match because it only involves keywords that are incompatible with 'frontend http-response header rule'`

I also need to test to origin header.